# html Audio currentTime and FileResult in asp.net MVC

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, audio

I have simple bit of code which is returning FileResult.

```
private FileResult TmpFileToClient()
{
    byte[] fileBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("some_file.mp3");
    return File(fileBytes, "audio/mpeg", "some_file.mp3");
}
```

This file method is using in Audio tag.`<audio src="guide/TmpFileToClient></audio>"` When I'm trying to change current time in JS to some value for some reason every time it starts over from 0 seconds. It works perfectly when audio tag uses path to file directly without server method. `<audio src="some_file.mp3></audio>"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anybody stuck with this problem  i solved it. Check your HTTP headers. I look at the headers returned by method and headers returned by direct url to file. In my case HTTP header "Accept-Ranges" was missed but in case direct url "Accept-Ranges" is equal "bytes". I added this header `Response.AddHeader("Accept-Ranges", "bytes");` and it works fine.